# PowerShell Script to list both CPU and GPU temperature

Tags: powershell, gpu, cpu, temperature, get-wmiobject

I'd like to grab from multiple machines CPU/GPU Temperature

So basically i`d like an output like this

COMPUTER NAME   CPU TEMPERATURE    GPU TEMPERATURE

COMPUTER001     80 Degrees         70 Degrees

then a list of every computer in a table or even better in a grid output format.

I have tested this code on my own machine here at home and it comes up with the following.....

```
Get-WmiObject : Not supported
At line:1 char:2
+  Get-WmiObject MSAcpi_ThermalZoneTemperature -Namespace "root/wmi"
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Get-WmiObject], ManagementException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetWMIManagementException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWmiObjectCommand
```

So this doesn't actually work for some reason, BUT if I do it on a machine at work it works? very confused.

Comment: You may share the actual code and information about Powershell version? PS version 6 and up do not have `Get-WmiObject` anymore. You should use the more modern `Get-CimInstance` anyway.

Comment: It varies with the computer model.  Some just don't support it.

Comment: Yes, various moving parts at work here; PoSh version, hardware/BIOS, CPU & GPU model. If you need reliable access to these values better use a dedicated tool.